# Почему ссылка не полностью занимает блок в лишке(flexbox)?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать чтобы текст 3 абзаца был в несколько строк. Именно этот элемент работает нормально, но остальные ссылки не хотят становиться в размер блока

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  /*делает менюшку по центру*/
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
  /*Задает размер менюшки*/
  background-color: #2696E8;
  /*Цвет фона менюшки*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: stretch;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2696E8;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  display: block
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #2696E8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2696E8
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Информация о том, как к нам доехать</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: У вас ссылка занимает всю ширину `li` - 100px.  В третьем `li` у вас текст вписывается ровно в блок, а в других текст ссылки меньше 100px.

Answer (score 1):

Так как `li` дочерний элемент `display: flex`, то достаточно заменить `width` на:

```
flex: 0 0 auto;
max-width: 100px;
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  /*делает менюшку по центру*/
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
  /*Задает размер менюшки*/
  background-color: #2696E8;
  /*Цвет фона менюшки*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: stretch;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2696E8;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}

a {
  display: block
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #2696E8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2696E8
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Информация о том, как к нам доехать</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно изменить `display` для `li` и задать размер ссылкам:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  /*делает менюшку по центру*/
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1000px;
  /*Задает размер менюшки*/
  background-color: #2696E8;
  /*Цвет фона менюшки*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: stretch;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #2696E8;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #2696E8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2696E8
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Информация о том, как к нам доехать</a></li>
  <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```